# How to match data to two conditions in a loop?

Tags: r, for-loop, datatable, match, vlookup

I'm having trouble building a data table that matches numbers based on two conditions (ID and date). Below is an example of a table snippet containing batch data.

| ID | Power | Fuel | Starting_date | Shutting_down_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| El_Bel | 344 | WB | 1983 | 2030 |
| El_Opo | 256 | WK | 1987 | 2027 |
| El_Tur | 400 | WB | 2019 | 2049 |

The question is how do I effectively match this data so that the data in the "Power" column is matched until the last year of operation by column "Shutting_down_date" is reached.

| Date | El_Bel | El_Opo | El_Tur |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2017 |  |  |  |
| 2018 |  |  |  |
| 2019 |  |  |  |
| 2020 |  |  |  |
| 2021 |  |  |  |

Many thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Which column should be "matched" with *Shutting_down_date*? I do not see any other column with a value that equals *Shutting_down_date*, so the result should be empty.

Comment: Basically the data from the column  _Power_ should be matched to the units in the column _ID_ until the date in the column _Shutting_down_date_.  The target table above is just a snippet, as the dates originally end in 2050.

Comment: In other words, there are two tables (data frames in R lingo) and you want to delete from the second table all entries (or set them to NA) where *Date* is greater than the corresponding *Shutting_down_date* in the first? Why do you not simply do this in a for loop over the levels of *ID*?

Comment: Yes exactly. I wrote the post because I'm a beginner programmer and I'm having some trouble writing a proper script for this solution.

Comment: I have posted an answer with the code. If this actually answers your question, please accept the answer so that the thread is marked as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us call the first dataframe `x` and the second data frame `y` and let us further assume that each *ID* only occurs once in the first table. The problem is that you have a different number of years for each *ID* which means that they cannot be stored in a `data.frame` (requires all columns to have the same length). You can use a `list`, though:

```
result <- list()
for (i in 1:nrow(x)) {
  id <- x[i,"ID"]
  end_date <- x[i,"Shutting_down_date"]
  result[[id]] <- subset(y[,c("Date",id)], Date <= end_date)
}
```

Then you can query the results as `result[["El_Bel"]]` or `result$El_Bel` etc.